# New user slips through the cracks

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I noticed that this question asked by a new user has gone unanswered:

[On the ring of integers of a compositum of number fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299710/daniel-a-marcus-number-fields-exercise-2-29)

Maybe I am being inappropriately paternal. But, especially since he/she did recognize what were warrented suggestions and modified his/her posting accordingly and got four upvotes (not that this is a criterion for eliciting a response), I think it would be nice if it got some response.

I am apprehensive as to whether this suggestion is fitting for here, but if I came across something similar in the context of my former business, I would definitely put it out there.

Thanks

Comment: I think these kind of requests should be brought up in the chat, and not on meta.  I do not think it is appropriate to advertise specific problems on the meta - even when you have very strong reasons for doing so.  

I vote to close as too localized.

Comment: Why not promoting the question with a bounty?

Comment: @Andrew I have posted an answer.

Comment: @EricNaslund May you say a few words why do you feel such advertisement is inappropriate?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  These type of questions are exactly what should be brought up in the chat.  I don't believe that Meta is meant to deal with very specific cases such as this.

Comment: I agree with @Eric. The software also gives any user with enough reputation (and Andrew here has more than enough) the ability to offer a bounty on any question and make it more visible and attractive. No need to post every less-attended question on the meta site.

Comment: @BenjaLim Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, In that there is already a bounty, I couldn't figure out how to add an incremental one. Would you please tell me. Also the point wasn't to edify an unattended question - there are plenty of them. Perhaps you would reread the entire transcript to see the motivation behind my post. Regards, Andrew

Comment: Andrew, the bounty was set nearly an hour after *this post* had been *closed*. I think it is safe to assume that your meta post caused initiating this bounty from the beginning. You could have done so yourself as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Forgive me, but perhaps I am not making myself clear. The point of this post was not to get the questioner's problem solved. I, perhaps misguidedly, felt that it would be nice if after the ensuing conversation subsequent to the post and the remedial steps taken by the new poster, that he/she got a response. My intention to add to the bounty was not to explicitly add to the incentive to provide a math answer to a math question, but to acknowledge the politesse of responder(s). Largesse over math.

Comment: Andrew, the site exists less than a 1,000 days but already has more than 100,000 questions. This means that on an average day we get 100 new questions posted. This is not counting the first year or so where the site was relatively slower. This means that we get nearly 3,000 questions in a single month. Out of those there are bound to be more than a handful of very polite people who don't get an answer. Do you intend to bring them all up on meta? If you posted a 50 points bounty you could have added a message that you do this because you feel this question deserves to be more noticed. (cont.)

Comment: (...) Instead what happens is that we have this elaborate and pointless discussion on what should be on the meta site, and you essentially contribute noise to a bog-like meta site. It serves no *real* purpose, at least not one that a bounty wouldn't have served. If you didn't want to post the bounty yourself that's a whole other thing, but regardless to that I feel that this sort of posts on the meta are wrong. There's no *problem* with the question, and there is no argument that the OP was really nice and put effort towards it. That's just how things are in a site with so much traffic.

Comment: Andrew, your posting on meta received a hostile edit after deletion.  I did not un-do the edit (and am not sure if I have that ability for deleted questions) but am letting you know in case you want to do so.  It is visible to anyone with over 10k "reputation" points, and to you.